# Is it obligatory to Pay Previous Zakaat after clearing off Debts

Tags: zakat

I would like to know if the below information is true or not.
I have heard this from one of my friend and she claims that she has got this info from reliable sources like Peace TV, well known and qualified Mufti's etc.

**The information is:**

Suppose a person has debts and the debt amount has exceeded the minimum Nisab amount. As his net amount was negative, the person did not give Zakaat in Year 1. However, he was able to clear off his debts up to considerate amount in Year 2 and he has savings on which Zakaat becomes obligatory. Hence, he gives Zakaat on the savings in Year 2.

But, according to my friend, this person needs to give the Zakaat from Year 1 as well in Year 2. Since he was not able to give Zakaat in Year 1 due to his debts, he needs to give Year 1's zakaat in Year 2. If he is not in a state to give the whole amount at once, he can distribute the money all over the year and pay off monthly/quarterly/whenever he can. BUT, still it is obligatory to pay off Year 1's Zakaat whether or not you are in debt. Summary is, After you clear off the debts, you need to give the previous year's Zakaats as well.

Hope I am not confusing you with the content.

I would like to know if this information is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Paying Zakat is a fundamental obligation upon those who meet the required conditions, such as owning a certain amount of wealth or assets for a minimum period of time. Zakat is considered a means of purification and a form of charity that benefits both the giver and the receiver.

If a person owes debts, they are still required to pay Zakat on their wealth, but they are allowed to subtract the amount of debt from their total wealth when calculating the Zakat due. This means that they should pay Zakat on the remaining amount of wealth that is above and beyond their debts.

However, if a person has missed paying Zakat in previous years, they are still required to make up for the missed payments, even if they have debts to repay. This is because Zakat is considered a separate and distinct obligation that cannot be waived or postponed.

In other words, paying off debts does not exempt a person from fulfilling their Zakat obligations. If a person has missed Zakat payments in previous years, they must make up for them as soon as possible, even if they have debts to repay.

It's important to note that Zakat should be given with the intention of fulfilling an obligation to God and seeking His pleasure, rather than as a means of seeking forgiveness or making up for past mistakes. It's also recommended to seek the guidance of a qualified Islamic scholar or financial advisor to ensure that Zakat obligations are fulfilled properly and in accordance with Islamic teachings.
To find out more about this please follow the link:
https://www.islamiqate.com/4664/how-is-zakat-determined-and-calculated

Answer (score -1):

Rule varies according to detailed information of issue, time and type of property ...

But generally:

The majority of scholars say that debt prevents the necessity of Zakat from inner money (Batinah), Such as cash, gold and silver and trade.

And therefore zakat not obligatory in money that if you have debt take all money or not left a full quorum (Nessap) after  pay the debt.